# How to force Chrome to request a javascript twice

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Run into an interesting case which I believe relates to Chrome's (maybe other browsers as well) optimization. Essentially, when the page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://myjavascripts.js"></script>
<script src="http://myjavascripts.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

The browser will request for myjavascript.js once, evident in the network tab, and reload whatever content inside myjavascript.js again.

```
Name | Status | time...
myjavascript.js | 200 | 40ms.
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to force the browser to send a second request to the same javascript file? For example:

```
Name | Status | time...
myjavascript.js | 200 | 40ms
myjavascript.js | 200 | 80ms
```

Also, out of curiosity, would there ever be a case where this is actually better than requesting it once?

Comment: Append some hash to the source?

Comment: "Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn’t stop to think if they should."

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve by requesting the same script twice?

Comment: Yeah, please explain your use case.

Comment: myjavascript.js?foo and myjavascript.js?bar

Answer (score 1):

You could do a cachebust:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://myjavascripts.js?q=1"></script>
<script src="http://myjavascripts.js?q=2"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

in other words append some random query parameter like timestamp to the url. This will make the browser think it's a different resource.

[More information here](https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting/)